# Does SDKMAN! install JRE only or also JDK?

Tags: java, sdkman

I'm trying to use VisualVM but I'm getting the following error:

> You are running VisualVM using Java Runtime Environment (JRE)

I'm using SDKMAN! to manage my Java versions

What should I do to make VisualVM work?

Comment: JDK includes a JRE. I also use sdkman and visualvm runs fine

Answer (score 0):

I stumble upon your question while trying to point Spring Tool Suite to the JDK's *JRE*. `sdkman` installs the [jdk](https://sdkman.io/usage) & the *JRE*.

The confusion is probably because there is no more a `jre` folder in the jdk as from **Java 9** as per [this explanation](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-relnotes.html#JDK-8049367). The important line is:

> The JDK and JRE run-time images have been restructured as documented
> in JEP 220.

The solution for me was to modify `SpringToolSuite4.ini`:

```
-vm
/home/jumping_monkey/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt/bin
```